# Regex match a dollar, without a backslash before it

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, escaping, regex-negation

I want to match only a dollar symbol without a backslash immediately before, as demonstrated below:

```
$not\$yes $  
^.........^
```

So far, I have [^\\]\$, but this doesn't match any dollar that begins a line. The dollar could be the first symbol in the document, so matching a newline would not work. How do I match this? Is the regex I have so far even right?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Javascript (GAS); it shouldn't matter too much except that in gs all the regex has to be escaped.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [an alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) with the [`^` anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) in order to match the `$` character literally if it is the first character in the string or if it follows a character that is not a backslash.

```
/(?:^|[^\\])\$/
```

#### Explanation:

- `(?:` - Start of a [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) that is used to group the alternation.
- `^|[^\\]` - [Alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) that matches the start of the string using the [`^` anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) **or** match a non-`\` character
- `)` - Close the non-capturing group that was used to group `^|[^\\]`
- `\$` - The `$` character literally

In other words, the `^` anchor will match the start of the string; while `[^\\]` will match anything but a backslash. The pipe `|` acts as an "or" operator that will match the start of the string or anything but a backslash (i.e., `^|[^\\]`).

So in the string you provided, the first/last `$` character would be matched.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain a bit more in depth exactly what this is is doing?

Comment: @JoeBob I added an explanation. Hopefully that clears it up. You can also test it out here -> https://regex101.com/r/nG8rO1/1

Answer (score 2):

Use a negative lookbehind assertion

```
(?<!\\)\$
```

In Action: https://regex101.com/r/dA8aA1/1

Comment: That's assuming negative lookbehinds are supported in the OP's language... but yeah.